# i need a code that lock cell when data enter in empty cell

Tags: javascript

Google Apps Script that will reject data while entering in non-empty cell and allow data to be entered in an empty cell, after which the cell will be locked as data is entered

i have tried few codes but isnt working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following VBA code to lock cells in Excel when data is entered:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Value <> "" Then
        Target.Locked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This code checks if only one cell has changed and if it contains a value. If both conditions are met, the cell is locked. To use this code, follow these steps:

Open your Excel workbook and go to the Developer tab.

Click on Visual Basic to open the VBA editor.

In the editor, right-click on the project name and select "Insert" > "Module".

Paste the code into the module.

Save the workbook and close the VBA editor.

Now, every time data is entered into a previously empty cell, the cell will be locked. Note that the code will only work in the worksheet where it is placed, so you may need to repeat the process for each worksheet in the workbook.